# I am trying to format a horizontal navigation list

Tags: html, css

So I want to format a horizontal navigation list. In my HTML page it says:

```
  <nav class="horizontal">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News &amp; Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members Only</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support GCC</a></li>
     </ul>
  </nav>
```

So in my css file I put this but it doesnt seem to work:

```
 Nav.Horizontal {
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:10px;
    letter-spacing:3px;
}

a:Nav.Horizontal {
    color:rgb(255,0,0)
}
```

Comment: where is your html? edit you question and add that

Comment: What do u  mean? they are both in the same file. I linked the css file  to it so i am 100% sure it works.

Comment: You need to include your HTML here so we can see what the problem is, because CSS is just for styling HTML.

Comment: also add display:inline-block;

Comment: You are not adding any styles to your html despite color. There's no way it can work. You should post your html so that we see the inner structure of the nav.

Comment: @TylerH yeah, im just trying to style it...

Comment: Upper / Lower case matters in CSS selectors, so your rule `Nav.Horizontal {...}` with uppercase `N` and `H` _does **not** match_ your HTML element `<nav class="horizontal">` with lowercase `n` and `h`

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
nav.horizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Also `a:Nav.horizontal` is an incorrect selector. In CSS, the `:` selector is used to select elements in a special state, like a visited link or a checked input. See [pseudo-clases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

If you want to style `a` inside your `nav` you should write `nav.horizontal a`. (Notice `nav` is in lowercase).

Comment: it would be of additional benefit if you could explain why the first selector was wrong (including what the `:` character is for in CSS selectors.

Comment: It simply has no sense there. I can't explain. `:` doesn't mean anything by itself. It is part of pseudo-classes, right?

Comment: Yes, I just mean some info like "a colon in CSS selectors is only used for X and Y, not for Z", etc.